# Why does this animation move to the bottom right?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have been working on this and I'm stuck as to why this animation moves my circles to the bottom right.  It pulses and scales properly and at the right times I want, but the circles start in the middle and skew to the bottom right of the div.

I want them to stay centered in the middle of the Div behind the header text

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #343434;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pulse {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 30rem;
}
.pulse circle {
  fill: #ff5154;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: pulse 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
.pulse circle:nth-child(2) {
  fill: #7fc6a4;
  animation: pulse 2s 1.75;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
.pulse circle:nth-child(3) {
  fill: #e5f77d;
  animation: pulse 2s 2.00; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
@keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="container">

    <h1>Pulse Animation</h1>

    <svg class="pulse" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
        <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
        <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a couple of alterations in your CSS to get this to work. I changed the top and left of the pulse class elements to be 0% instead of 50% and then used [transform-origin](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) on the circle class elements to center them.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');
h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #343434;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pulse {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  max-width: 30rem;
}
.pulse circle {
  fill: #ff5154;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: pulse 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
.pulse circle:nth-child(2) {
  fill: #7fc6a4;
  animation: pulse 2s 1s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
.pulse circle:nth-child(3) {
  fill: #e5f77d;
  animation: pulse 2s 2s; 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.5, 0, 1);
}
@keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Pulse Animation</h1>
 <svg class="pulse" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
  <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
  <circle id="Oval" cx="512" cy="512" r="512"></circle>
 </svg>
</div>
```